# How many Redirect rules can be added to Apache before performance is affected?

Tags: apache, redirect

I am migrating part of a site from using an old URL naming scheme to a new one. The old URLs do not contain enough information to generate the new URLs. Therefore, I can't write a single rule to redirect them all.

There are about 700 pages which need to be redirected. If I write a script to manually generate all the Redirect rules for me, then add them to an Apache config, how severely will these rules affect performance?

Comment: If you use [RewriteMap with DBM hash file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm), I don't think 700 rules will affect performance.

Comment: Thanks Dusan. How much of a difference does dbm make over a txt file? I understand that it might be more efficient for startup, but surely once the map is in memory, it doesn't make any difference?

Comment: I think you are correct, but you will have to measure it to be sure :)